# How to merge two dicts in a single one

Tags: python

I have:

```
a = {'name':'alfred','class':'2'}
b = {'year':'1990','town':'NY'}
```

And I want to merge a and b to get:

```
{'name':'alfred','class':'2', 'year':'1990','town':'NY'}
```

So far I created a new dict and iterate through both to set key values pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3.9

```
c = a | b
```

Python3.5+

```
c = {**a, **b}
```

Comment: This question is a clear duplicate showing no effort.  Perhaps avoid answering it.

Comment: Thank you Synthase. And sorry for the duplicate.